# How do I skip the OTP passphrase prompt for sudo but keep it for ssh?

Tags: ssh, debian, sudo, pam

I've configured a server to support OTP (using opie) with ssh.  What annoys me is that I get the OTP passphrase prompt even for root when doing sudo.  How can I configure PAM to suppress it?  Don't see a need for OTP *locally*.

System is Debian stable (lenny), with minor unstable/backports installed (nothing connected to PAM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is "the Debian way" to do it, but:

You should have an `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file which specifies which PAM modules sudo will use for authentication (and other stuff) -- Find the module for your one-time password magic and comment it out.  The lines you're looking for probably look something like:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_opie.so             no_warn no_fake_prompts
auth            requisite       pam_opieaccess.so       no_warn allow_local
```

On Debian systems a lot of PAM configurations reference `common-*` files -- If that's the case copy the contents of those files in place of the `include` directive.

---

Sage advice: Launch screen & su to root inside it before you start editing so you have a root shell to fix stuff if you need it; Also obviously make a backup of the original file so you can get it back if you need to.

Comment: If the sudo pam configuration isn't in `/etc/pam.d` or `/usr/local/etc/pam.d` you can also try `locate sudo | grep -i pam` -- That shouldn't be a huge list & should have the file you're looking for :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's it, though I'm looking into moving opie into sshd (as that's where it's actually required).